# PostMethod/HttpClient

Tags: java, http-post, httpclient, apache-httpclient-4.x

I need to make a http post request to the below URL with the URL parameters along with the XML. I am trying with below code and not able to get proper response back.

```
URL - https://mytest.com?z=123&b=abc&c=%10

xml - <test>
        <data> This is test XML </data>
      </test>

public String getResponse(String xml) {

    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    String url="https://mytest.com";
    PostMethod pMethod = new pMethod(url);
    pMethod.addParameter("z","123");
    pMethod.addParameter("b","abc");
    pMethod.addParameter("c","%10");
    post.setRequestEntity(new StringRequestEntity(xml, "application/xml", "UTF-8"));
    client.executeMethod(pMethod);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please elaborate what kind of response you are expecting? If you are facing problem only in sending xml string to the given URL then may be [Send Xml string through POST method in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23760477/send-xml-string-through-post-method-in-java) could help you.

Comment: I am expecting XML response. Since this is http post request, I want to hide my URL parameters. Along with URL parameters, I need to post the XML. I am not able to do both together (encode URL parameters+ posting the XML).